# Matching extent (samples & lines) to get multi-temporal stack

Tags: landsat, envi, stack, enmap-box

I downloaded several Landsat scenes (4x3) to create some multi-temporal stacks to see the phenological difference in April/March - mid summer - autumn. I actually use The EnMap Box which has been developed by my university.

I alreadly stacked the 7 bands of each scene without problems. Now the programm tells me that the 3 scenes don't have the same spatial size. In the .hdr data the samples and lines are not exactly the same what should cause the problem.

[image: How my problem looks like]

How can I solve that issue?

Answer (score 0):

From the ENVI main menu bar, select Basic Tools Resize Data (Spatial/Spectral). The Input File dialog appears. Select the file and input the required samples and lines to match with other scenes. This should solve your problem.